# finding the limit of an increasing, positive function

Tags: calculus, limits

I have been asked to find the limit of a function via the squeeze theorem.  Is my approach reasonable.

[image: the question]

Here is my proposed solution.

[image: My solution]

Overall, it seems too simplistic.

Comment: Correctness does not depend on simpleness and yes,  your solution is correct.

Comment: It is basically fine. For the first line, I would prefer simply $\frac{f(x)}{f(x)}\le \frac{f(2x)}{f(x)}\le \frac{f(3x)}{f(x)}$. Then the two limit results on the next line, then the conclusion. The way you have it, it seems that you are already taking for granted that the limit of the middle ratio exists.

Comment: Sometimes, it is too simple to believe it to be true.

Comment: You showed that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/f(x) = 1 = \lim_{x \to \infty} f(3x)/f(x)$, but one thing I would include is that $f(x)/f(x) \leq f(2x)/f(x) \leq f(3x)/f(x)$. This is a fundamental assumption for the Squeeze Theorem.